# If not true, prompt again until is true

Tags: c++

This is so easy, but I am drawing a blank right now (long day). I simply need this part of the code to reprompt for a file name if the one entered is not valid or is bad.

```
cout << "Please enter a file name:" << endl;
string filename;
string line;
cin >> filename;
ifstream in_file;
in_file.open(filename.c_str());


    if (in_file.good())
    {
        getline (in_file, line);
        cout << line << endl;
        in_file.close();
    }
```

Comment: How about putting your code into a function that returns true if all was okay, and false if not, and then call it in a loop like that : `while ( !processfile()) std::cerr << "Incorrect file.\n" ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while cicle and break it if there is a valid input.

```
while (1) {
    cout << "Please enter a file name:" << endl;
    string filename;
    string line;
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open(filename.c_str());


    if (in_file.good())
    {
        getline (in_file, line);
        cout << line << endl;
        in_file.close();
        break; // breaks the while
    }
}
```

Comment: That was what I was trying to get at. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use a loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

for (std::string filename;
     std::cout << "Enter filename: " && std::getline(std::cin, filename); )
{
    if (std::ifstream infile(filename))
    {
        std::string line;
        if (std::getline(infile, line))
        {
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "Could not open file '" << filename << "', please try again.\n";
}
```

(You can of course reuse the outer string in the inner operation if you like.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to always perform an action once, but repeat it if some condition is true.

So a `do-while` loop is the correct approach:

```
ifstream in_file;
string filename;
string line;

do {
    cout << "Please enter a file name:" << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    in_file.open(filename.c_str());
} while (!in_file.good());

getline (in_file, line);
cout << line << endl;
in_file.close();
```